# Generate Linq Or Clause from List of Enumeration

Tags: c#, linq

Greetings Overflowers,

I am working on an application that allows for a user to generate a custom report and I have a scenario where I need to generate a Linq Or clause from a list of enumeration values.  The problem I'm having is I cannot see an elegant way of generating the Or clause.

For example:

```
//Enumeration of possible 'OR' conditions
public enum Conditions
{
    ByAlpha,
    ByBeta,
    ByGamma
}

//'Entity' I'm querying against.
class ResultObject
{
    public bool AlphaValue { get; set; }
    public bool BetaValue { get; set; }
    public bool GammaValue { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Create list of desired conditions.  
        //Basically I want this to mimic the query, 
        // "Show me all of the ResultObjects where the AlphaValue is true or the GammaValue is true".
        var conditions = new List<Conditions>
        {
            Conditions.ByAlpha,
            Conditions.ByGamma
        };

        //Sample collection of objects.  This would normally be a collection of EF entities. 
        var sampleCollection = new List<ResultObject>
        {
            new ResultObject
            {
                Name = "Sample 1",
                AlphaValue = true,
                BetaValue = true,
                GammaValue = true,
            },
            new ResultObject
            {
                Name = "Sample 2",
                AlphaValue = false,
                BetaValue = false,
                GammaValue = false,
            },
            new ResultObject
            {
                Name = "Sample 3",
                AlphaValue = true,
                BetaValue = false,
                GammaValue = true,
            }
        };

        var sampleCollectionQueryable = sampleCollection.AsQueryable();

        //This should filter the sampleCollection down to containing only the 
        //"Sample 3" ResultObject; instead, it filters out all of the ResultObjects.
        var query = GenerateOrClause(sampleCollectionQueryable, conditions);
    }

    static IQueryable<ResultObject> GenerateOrClause(IQueryable<ResultObject> query, List<Conditions> conditions)
    {
        //This approach generates a series of AND statements, instead I need a series of OR statements
        //for each condition.
        foreach (var condition in conditions)
        {
            switch (condition)
            {
                case Conditions.ByAlpha:
                    query = query.Where(x => x.AlphaValue);
                    break;
                case Conditions.ByBeta:
                    query = query.Where(x => x.BetaValue);
                    break;
                case Conditions.ByGamma:
                    query = query.Where(x => x.GammaValue);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }

        return query;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You would need to construct the expression tree yourself. If adding a new library to your project is an option, have a look at [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) which does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make `Conditions` a `Flags` enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum Conditions {
    ByNone = 0,
    ByAlpha = 1,
    ByBeta = 2,
    ByGamma = 4
}
```

and change your ResultObject:

```
class ResultObject {
    public Conditions Conditions { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then you can say:

```
var conditions = new List<Conditions> { Conditions.ByAlpha, Conditions.ByGamma };
var matches = sampleCollection
                  .Where(x => conditions.Select(c => c & x != 0).Any());
```

This *is* the right design for the problem that you're trying to solve.

If for some reason you need to keep your current `ResultObject`, which I will now call `OldResultObject` for the sake of clarity:

```
class OldResultObject {
    public bool AlphaValue { get; set; }
    public bool BetaValue { get; set; }
    public bool GammaValue { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

it's easy to project that to a new `ResultObject`:

```
var resultObject = new ResultObject {
    Conditions =
        (oldResultObject.AlphaValue ? Conditions.ByAlpha : Conditions.ByNone) | 
        (oldResultObject.BetaValue ? Conditions.ByBeta : Conditions.ByNone) |
        (oldResultObject.GammaValue ? Conditions.ByGamma : Conditions.ByNone),
    Name = oldResult.Name;
}
```

so this is really *very* little effort on your part to redesign at all.

Answer (score 2):

You could also probably use a Union if you don't want to have to change the code you have very much:

```
static IQueryable<ResultObject> GenerateOrClause(IQueryable<ResultObject> query, List<Conditions> conditions)
{
    if( conditions.Count == 0 )
        return query;

    var resultQuery = new List<ResultObject>().AsQueryable();

    foreach (var condition in conditions)
    {
        switch (condition)
        {
            case Conditions.ByAlpha:
                resultQuery = resultQuery.Union(query.Where(x => x.AlphaValue));
                break;
            case Conditions.ByBeta:
                resultQuery = resultQuery.Union(query.Where(x => x.BetaValue));
                break;
            case Conditions.ByGamma:
                resultQuery = resultQuery.Union(query.Where(x => x.GammaValue));
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    return resultQuery;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using Expression Trees:

```
private IQueryable<ResultObject> GenerateOrClause(IQueryable<ResultObject> query,
                                                  IList<Conditions> conditions)
{
    if( conditions.Count == 0 )
        return query;

    var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ResultObject), "c");
    Expression builder = GetProperty(pe, conditions.First());

    foreach(var condition in conditions.Skip(1))
    {
        var property = GetProperty(pe, condition);
        builder = Expression.OrElse(builder, property);
    }

    var predicate = Expression.Lambda(builder, pe);

    return query.Where((Func<ResultObject, bool>)predicate.Compile()).AsQueryable();
}

private static MemberExpression GetProperty(ParameterExpression pe,
                                            Conditions condition)
{
    MemberExpression property;

    switch (condition)
    {
        case Conditions.ByAlpha:
            property = Expression.Property(pe, "AlphaValue");
            break;
        case Conditions.ByBeta:
            property = Expression.Property(pe, "BetaValue");
            break;
        case Conditions.ByGamma:
            property = Expression.Property(pe, "GammaValue");
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }

    return property;
}
```

I would recommend using the `Flags` solution by Jason.

Here is a sample of the predicate generated:

```
GenerateOrClause(Enumerable.Empty<ResultObject>().AsQueryable(),
                 new List<Conditions> { Conditions.ByAlpha });
// (c.AlphaValue)

GenerateOrClause(Enumerable.Empty<ResultObject>().AsQueryable(),
                 new List<Conditions> { Conditions.ByAlpha, Conditions.ByBeta });
// (c.AlphaValue OrElse c.BetaValue)

GenerateOrClause(Enumerable.Empty<ResultObject>().AsQueryable(),
                 new List<Conditions> { Conditions.ByAlpha, Conditions.ByBeta, Conditions.ByGamma });
// ((c.AlphaValue OrElse c.BetaValue) OrElse c.GammaValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

.Where is an extension method on IEnumerable < T >, which takes a predicate of type Func. Why not create a List < Func < T,bool > > ` with your predicates like x => x.AlphaValue, and when you have this list, iterate it and passing the values in a .Where on your IEnumerable?

Hope i was able to tell you what i have in mind...

Comment: This is incorrect in this context. `IQueryable<T>.Where` takes an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, not a `Func<T, bool>`.

Comment: @SimonBelanger Ok you're right, i had IEnumerable in my mind, but the question is about IQueryable...